# How to say "he is a postdoc researcher in philosophy" in German?

Tags: word-choice, preposition, article

> Er ist **ein** postdoc Forscher **in/für** Philosophie.

Does it require "ein"? Should it be *Postdoc-Forscher* or separate? And should I use *in* or *für*?

Comment: Neither would one say *postdoc researcher* in English, nor *PostDoc-Forscher* in German. I would simply say *„Er ist PostDoc in der Philosophie.“*

Comment: Had to google "postdoc", never heard it before... but I would not use camel case here... so "Er ist Postdoc in der Philosophie" would be my preferred way of writing that. Or if you completely want to translate this it would be "Er ist Postdoktorand in der Philosophie", that would avoid the anglicism.

Comment: Postdoc-Forscher sounds like somebody who conducts research about postdocs.

Answer (score 2):

I may not be doing philosophy, but I describe myself and my job as:

> Ich bin Postdoc (in Chemie) an der Uni Kyoto.

You can also use *arbeiten als* but contrary to the other answer I would not say **einen Postdoc machen* because it is a job, not a title I wish to ultimately gain. (I did say *Ich mache meinen Doktor* at my previous university; for the job, the job title *Doktorand* exists.)

(It was pointed out that there are other things such as *ein FSJ, ein Praktikum* that would be usable with *machen*. Those things are countable; even though I am on my second postdoc position I wouldn’t say that this is my **zweiter Postdoc*. There is only one postdoc phase but it can be made up of multiple positions at different universities.)

As for the *ein*, if you wish to imply he is one of many then it should be there. If you are just stating his profession then it would usually be left out.

Hardly anybody would say *Postdoc-Forscher* or *Postdocforscher* (a space would be wrong; putting a space in noun compounds in German is condescendingly called a *Deppenleerzeichen*). These aren’t technically wrong they’re just overspecified as a postdoc is already a researcher. In English, the construction *postdoctoral researcher* exists which doesn’t have a direct parallel equivalent in German as far as I am aware.

Comment: Schonmal *eine Weiterbildung, ein Praktikum, ein FSJ* gemacht? Titel bekommen?

Comment: Ist das den Üblich in Deutsch, im entsprechenden Umfeld? Ich konnte mir lange nichts konkretes unter dem Begriff vorstellen, sowie mir keine deutsche Entsprechung bekannt ist. Die Frage lädt doch eine knackige (etablierte) Übersetzung ein, aber hier steht keine.

Comment: @vectory Der Begriff "Postdoc" ist im Forschungssektor Gang und Gäbe, ich habe nie einen eingedeutschten Begriff dafür gehört oder gelesen. Vielleicht sind Akademiker (eventuell mit Ausnahme von Germanisten?) weniger allergisch gegen Fremdworte als manche anderen Leute, die teilweise geradezu besessen davon sind, für alles einen eigenständigen deutschen Begriff kreieren zu müssen? (Mich persönlich stört nur, wenn bereits etablierte deutsche Worte durch Fremdworte - heutzutage üblicherweise Anglizismen - verdrängt werden, weil letztere ja so "in" sind.)

Comment: This is the same as mentioned in my answer except it claims *einen Postdoc machen* is not possible to say except I've used and heard it first hand.

Comment: @vectory Es gibt den Begriff *Postdoktorand*, der eher einen lateinischen Ursprung anklingen lässt. Er ist aber lang, deswegen wird er abgekürzt. Dabei kommt *Postdok.* heraus, das wird aber, wahrscheinlich wegen der Nähe zum Englischen, fast ausschließlich mit -c geschrieben.

Comment: Obiger Kommentar CC @VolkerLandgraf

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can say

> Er ist Postdoc in Philosophie

Although to me it sounds more natural to say

> Er macht seinen Postdoc in Philosophie

Or a bit more formal:

> Er absolviert seinen Postdoc in Philosophie.

An independent postdoctoral researcher would be:

> Er ist ein unabhängiger Postdoc in Philosophie.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass man einen Postdoc machen kann, das ist kein Titel, den man erringen kann, sondern die Beschreibung einer Tätigkeit... deshalb würde ich den zweiten Teil entfernen (dann auch Upvote von mir)

Comment: Man erlangt keinen Abschluss, aber es ist als weitere Qualifikation nötig. Idealerweise macht man 2-4 Jahre einen Postdoc um danach eine feste Stelle als Professor zu besetzen.

Comment: @TorstenLink *Ich mache ein FSJ*.

Comment: @infinitezero man **macht** keinen Postdoc (allenfalls kann man *sehr* umgangssprachlich sagen: *er macht einen auf Postdoc*) - Als Postdocs bezeichnet man Forscher auf einer (zeitlich befristeten) Stelle, die mit enem promovierten Bewerber zu besetzen ist und bei der kein Hinarbeiten auf eine Habilitation vorgesehen ist. Feste Stellen für Promovierte beinhalten dagegen üblicherweise mindestens die Option, oft auch die mehr oder weniger dezente Aufforderung, auf eine Habilitation hinzuarbeiten. Die Habilitation ist wiederum Voraussetzung für das Besetzen einer Professorenstelle.

Comment: Also bei uns sagen alle sie machen ihren Postdoc.  Man kann auch fragen "Machst Du nach deinem Doktor einen Postdoc?" Das hat nichts mit "auf etwas machen" zu tun. Zumal ich auch gar nicht wüsste, was einen Postdoc so speziell charakterisiert, dass man einen "auf Postdoc machen kann". (Hessen)

Comment: @infinitezero man kann sich als Nicht-Postdoc so aufspielen als sei man einer, dann macht man einen auf Postdoc.

Comment: Ja... mir ist bewusst was das heißt, mir ist aber nicht bewusst, wie man sich so aufspielen könnte.....

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf und an alle Downvoter: *einen Postdoc machen* ist eine absolut übliche Formulierung (ein Beleg [hier](https://www.zeit.de/campus/2014/04/doktorarbeit-promotion-wirtschaft/seite-2)). Die Unterstellung, daß sich *machen* nur mit einem Titel verbinden könne, ist doch lächerlich, siehe *ein FSJ, ein Praktikum, eine Weiterbildung machen*.

Comment: @DavidVogt nur um das klarzustellen: von mir stammt der Downvote nicht - dazu ist mir die "danebene" Formulierung bei Weitem nicht schlimm genug. Zu Deinen vermeintlichen Gegenbeispielen: Das sind Dinge, bei denen man *machen* als umgangssprachliches Synonym für *absolvieren* verwendet. Aber der Postdoc ist eine Person, so wie der Praktikant, der ein Praktikum macht/absolviert. Eine Postdoc-Stelle hingegen absolviert man nicht, man arbeitet oder sitzt auf einer oder hat sie inne. Was *ein* Doktorand bei einem mündlichen Interview salopp gesagt hat, ist für mich kein Beleg für "absolut üblich"

Comment: Natürlich absolviert man einen Postdoc. Ein Postdoc ist keine permanente Stelle oder Position, schon gar nicht in Deutschland, wo das Zeitarbeitsgesetz einem da irgendwann einen Riegel vorschiebt. Das heißt man befindet sich immer in einer Übergangsphase, die üblicherweise in 2 Jahres Rhythmen absolviert wird. Je am Ende der zwei Jahre hat man die Möglichkeit einen weitere Postdocstelle zu belegen, in eine permanente Stelle zu kommen (hahaha) oder dann doch auf den freien Arbeitsmarkt zu wechseln.

Comment: Die Arbeitsgruppen in CENIDE sind jederzeit an hochqualifizierten und motivierten promovierten Wissenschaftlerinnen und Wissenschaftlern interessiert, die gerne einen Postdoc absolvieren möchten. [Universität Duisburg Essen](https://www.uni-due.de/cenide/ausbildung.php)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Jetzt wird mir erst klar, woher das Unbehagen stammt. Ich bin nie davon ausgegangen, daß *Postdoc* ausschließlich eine Person bezeichnet. In *einen Postdoc machen* hat man den Eindruck, daß es um einen Lebensabschnitt (wissenschaftliches Arbeiten nach dem Erwerb des Doktorgrads) geht; daher die Parallele zu *ein Auslandssemester, FSJ machen*. Hier noch ein paar [Beispiele](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=56V1CgAAQBAJ&v=snippet&q=%22einen%20postdoc%22) aus einem Buch. Ein apodiktisches "das sagt man nicht" ist für mich hier nicht angemessen.

Comment: How to say "he is a **postdoctoral researcher** in philosophy" or "he is an **independent postdoctoral researcher** in philosophy".

Comment: @infinitezero Wenn jemand von unten (z. B. Masterand) Können, Kompetenz oder Autorität vortäscht, als wäre sie Postdoc. Genau wie ein Lehrling einen auf Meister machen kann.

Comment: Hm. Mag sein, dass das in manchen Fächern geht, im naturwissenschaftlichen Sektor fällt sowas eigentlich direkt auf.

Comment: It's a pity this is still downvoted although it's a correct answer